# Continuity of integrand required or sufficient condition for differentiability of the integral

Tags: integration

Let $A(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$, for each $x \in [a, b]$. The first fundamental theorem of calculus states if $f$ is continuous at $c \in [a, b]$, then $A'(c)$ exists.

Does the implication go in the other direction too? In other words, can $A'(x)$ exist even if $f(x)$ is not continuous?

Thanks!

Comment: btw you should be careful with your wording. The FTC says "$A'(c)$ exists and equals $f(c)$". As the answer below shows, it is possible for $A$ to be differentiable everywhere (it's even the constant zero function). The difference is that $A'(0)\neq f(0)$. In your final statement you once again need to be careful with wording. "Does the implication go in the other direction too?" No. The second question "In other words..." is actually a different question, the answer to which is Yes. so your use of "in other words" is misleading.

Comment: I agree it is confusing the way I wrote it. Sorry about that! I would leave the question as is, because it was answered nevertheless, and it might be good for posterity to know what your comment refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the other implication does not hold. Consider $$f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R,t\mapsto\begin{cases}1&\text{for }t=0,\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Obviously, $f$ is not continuous, but $A(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, which is differentiable. However, you can add conditions on $f$ for this result to hold, for example monotonicity, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187908/first-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-corollary)

Answer (score 1):

For the **Lebesgue integral**, there is an important result due to Lebesgue.  If $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$, then
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\;dt
$$
is differentiable almost everywhere and $F'(t) = f(x)$ almost everywhere.  This could happen even if $f$ is nowhere continuous.  There is a certain technical description of points $x$ (now called **Lebesgue points**) where it is guaranteed that $F'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks!