# Prove that $f\left(x_0\right)=a$

Tags: integration

> Suppose that $f$ has an anti-derivative $F$ on an interval $I$, i.e. $F^{\prime}(x)=f(x)$ holds for all $x \in I$. Let $x_0 \in I$ such that $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0+} f(x)=a$. Prove that $f\left(x_0\right)=a$

---

The solution given in the note goes like this:

> For any $x>x_0$, we apply MVT on $F$ to say that there exists $c_x \in\left(x_0, x\right)$ such that
> $$
> \frac{F(x)-F\left(x_0\right)}{x-x_0}=F^{\prime}\left(c_x\right)=f\left(c_x\right) .
> $$
> Now letting $x \rightarrow x_0^{+}$, the above LHS converges to $F^{\prime}\left(x_0\right)=f\left(x_0\right)$. Since $x_0<c_x<x \Longrightarrow c_x \rightarrow x_0^{+}$, so the RHS of (2) converges to $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0^{+}} f\left(c_x\right)=$ $\lim _{c_{x \rightarrow x_0^{+}}} f\left(c_x\right)=a$. Hence we get the desired conclusion.

---

I have two questions:

1. At the very beginning, they apply MVT on $F$, which can only be applied to differentiable functions. We know, by FTC that an antiderivative $F$ of the function $f$ is differentiable only at point where $f$ is continuous. It is not given in the problem that $f$ is continuous, then how do they use MVT?
2. How does $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0^{+}} f\left(c_x\right)=$ $\lim _{c_{x \rightarrow x_0^{+}}} f\left(c_x\right)=a$ imply $f\left(x_0\right)=a$?

Answer (score 1):

> At the very beginning, they apply MVT on F
> , which can only be applied to differentiable functions. We know, by FTC that an antiderivative F
> of the function f
> is differentiable only at point where f
> is continuous. It is not given in the problem that f
> is continuous, then how do they use MVT?

It is a given that $F$ is differentiable everywhere.

> How does limx→x+0f(cx)=
> limcx→x+0f(cx)=a
> imply f(x0)=a
> ?

Like you said, if $F$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous.Then, $$a=\lim_{c_x\rightarrow x_0} f(c_x)=f\left(\lim_{c_x\rightarrow x_0} c_x\right)=f(x_0)$$

If you want more insight on why $f$ is continuous, refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4346840/959336).

Comment: Wait, if it's given that $F$ is differentiable and which implies that $f$ is continuous, then from that, we could have directly deduced the result then?

Comment: @math_learner Yes

Comment: @math_learner correct. I suppose that the goal of the exercise was to also argue diff of $F \implies$ continuity of $f$